# With Ionic, how can I detect when call has been disconnected?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

The Ionic [documentation for `call-number`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number) is scant.

I'm trying to figure out how I can detect when a call has been disconnected. I want my app to fire a message and update a database (with call duration and other metadata) upon call completion.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two ways a phone call could end and that is handled by the `onSuccess` and `onError` parameters of the `callNumber` function, you can provide the handling of the call end database log via these functions.

ie.

```js
this.callNumber.callNumber(
    successres => {
        // handle the success result 
        console.log(successres);
    }, 
    err => {
        // handle errors while calling
        console.log(err);
    }, 
    "18001010101", 
    true);
```

Comment: Yes but a busy signal will still trigger the `success` won't it? I want to know specifically WHY the call has been ended (did user hang up, was call disconnected, was there a busy signal, etc )

Comment: you should rephrase the question to focus on that aspect, at that point, wont successres contain such information?